# Adding values (Sum) of RDD in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have two spark RDDs with N number of elements.

**e.g.**

```
rdd1= [1,2,5,7,50,....] 
rdd2= [5,7,5,6,8,.....]
```

How to add them and have an output like `[6,9,10,13,58,....]`?
Kindly provide solution using Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `zip` the RDD's and map `sum` over the created tuples

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1,2,5,7,50])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([5,7,5,6,8])

print(rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(sum).collect())
```

Output

```
[6, 9, 10, 13, 58]
```